# Overriding static inherited static variable

Tags: c#

I have a abstract class User with accessFlag static integer and then I have multiple classes that inherit this one with different accessFlag e.g. student, administrator, teacher. All of those classes have to include accessFlag but I would want to set it in those classes like in administrator static accessFlag = 2;

With the code below right now when I create administrator and display accessFlag it display 0 instead of 2. I assume I could create getters and setters in administrator and then I would get the proper value but I don't want to have so much duplicated code in every class that inherits from user getters and setters for accessFlag.

```
 abstract public class User
    {
        static int accessFlag;

        public int AccessFlag
        {
            get
            {
                return accessFlag;
            }

            set
            {
                accessFlag = value;
            }
        }
    }
    public class Administrator: User
        {
            static int accessFlag = 2;
        }
```

Comment: Static members are not inherited. So you also cannot override them.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't want static here. Have you considered an interface instead?

Comment: @poke what if it was non-static field? I still would have to write override getters and setters in every class that inherits user class

Eris Well interfaces only allow methods so I'm not sure if thats the best idea

Comment: abstract public class User
    {

        abstract public int AccessFlag
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
    public class Administrator : User
    {
         int accessFlag = 2;

         public override int AccessFlag
         {
             get
             {
                 return accessFlag;
             }
             set
             {
                 value = accessFlag; 
             }
         }
    } this has to be the correct implementation

Comment: @viveknuna Does it make more sense than deleting the variable from user and creating static variables in everyone of those classes? or just set the accessFlag in constructor in everyone of those classes?

Comment: It’s absolutely unclear what the purpose of that property is. Whether the value is supposed to be fixed for each `User` subtype, or whether it’s actually settable, and whether all instances should get that updated value or not.

Comment: @Poke the values would be static for each class so for example Administrator it would be static and set to 2, Teacher static and set to 1 etc. I am looking for the best way to not duplicate a lot of code and for it to make, sense maybe the interface would be the most proper way

Comment: Then you absolutely don’t want a setter there. Just declare an `public abstract int AccessFlag { get; }` in the `User` class, and then let every subclass implement this with a read-only property in each subclass, e.g. `public int AccessFlag => 2` (using C# 6 syntax for read-only properties)

Comment: @poke Thank you thats perfect, should I delete the question?

Comment: Glad I could help you. You can keep the question where it is, it will be cleaned up automatically later.

Answer (score 0):

There is no language supported how to do it. The best is still to override getters and setters for the property. By the way I don't think setter makes any sense here.

The only option how to achieve it without that is the reflection. In the getter you would call `GetType ()` on the object and ask for the member `accessFlag` on that class. But it would be quite slow and ugly.